How to use sql api create Array column and send elasticsearch?
I encountered an issue while using Flink CDC to sync data from MySQL to Elasticsearch. There's a one-to-many relationship between two MySQL tables, "matcher" and "matcher_task".
Table：
CREATE TABLE `matcher`(
  `id`bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `position_code`varchar(100),
  `talent_code`varchar(60),
  `talent_flag` tinyint(1)
);

CREATE TABLE `matcher_task` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `matcher_id` bigint,
  `employee_code` varchar(60),
  `read_flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `step` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL 
);

I want to store "matcher_task" data in Elasticsearch within a field “taskJson” of type "nested" in an index.
Index：
"matcher_index": {
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "positionCode": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "taskJson": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "matcherId": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "employeeCode": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "readFlag": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "step": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Version:

Elasticsearch:6
Flink:1.14

Initially, I wanted to use Flink SQL aggregate functions to solve this problem, but Flink 1.14 does not support the syntax for aggregate functions.
function: JSON_OBJECT,JSON_ARRAYAGG
SOURCE：
<entry key="SOURCE">
        CREATE TABLE matcher_task_source (
            `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
            `matcher_id` BIGINT,
            `employee_code` STRING,
            `read_flag` INT,
            `step` INT,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`) NOT ENFORCED
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'mysql-cdc',
            'hostname' = '${mysql_host}',
            'port' = '${mysql_port}',
            'username' = '${mysql_username}',
            'password' = '${mysql_password}',
            'database-name' = '${mysql_database}',
            'table-name' = 'matcher_task',
        )
</entry>

SINK:
    <entry key="SINK">
    CREATE TABLE matcher_index (
            `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
            `taskJson` ARRAY<ROW<`id` STRING, `matcherId` STRING, `employeeCode` STRING, `readFlag` STRING, `step` STRING>>,
            PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'elasticsearch-6',
            'hosts' = '${es_url}',
            ${es_auth}
            'index' = 'matcher_index',
            'document-type' = '_doc'
        )
    </entry>

<!--          -->

<entry key="SINK">
        INSERT INTO matcher_index
        select mt.resume_id as id,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'id',mt.id,
            'matcherId',mt.matcher_id,
            'employeeCode',mt.employee_code,
            'readFlag',mt.read_flag,
            'step',mt.step
        )
    ) AS taskJson
from matcher_task_source mt
GROUP BY mt.resume_id
</entry>

I attempted to use a Flink UDF (User-Defined Function "JsonConcatAgg") to solve it, but it still didn't work!
SINK:
<entry key="SINK">
        INSERT INTO matcher_index
        select mt.resume_id as id,
    JsonConcatAgg(
        mt.id,
        mt.matcherId,
        mt.read_flag,
        mt.employee_code,
        mt.step
    ) AS taskJson
from matcher_task_source mt
GROUP BY mt.resume_id
</entry>

Java:
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.apache.flink.table.functions.AggregateFunction;

public class JsonConcatAggFunction extends AggregateFunction<String, JsonConcatAggFunction.Accumulator> {

    public static class Accumulator {
        public String jsonArray = "[";
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(JsonConcatAggFunction.Accumulator accumulator) {
        if (accumulator.jsonArray.length() > 1) {
            accumulator.jsonArray += "]";
            return accumulator.jsonArray;
        }
        return "[]";
    }

    @Override
    public JsonConcatAggFunction.Accumulator createAccumulator() {
        return null;
    }

    public void accumulate(Accumulator acc, String id, String matcherId, String readFlag, String employeeCode, String step) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", id);
        jsonObject.addProperty("matcherId", matcherId);
        jsonObject.addProperty("readFlag", readFlag);
        jsonObject.addProperty("employeeCode", employeeCode);
        jsonObject.addProperty("step", step);

        if (acc.jsonArray.length() > 1) {
            acc.jsonArray += ",";
        }
        acc.jsonArray += jsonObject.toString();
    }
}

